# What are all the envelope status values for Docusign, and what transitions are allowed?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm a beginner at Docusign, and I seem to keep winding up here whenever I look for help.

Anyway, I just want to know all possible values for envelope status. I know there's 'created', 'sent', 'voided', 'declined', 'completed' and 'delivered'. Are there any others?

Part 2 of my question is what transitions are allowed? This includes whether a reversal is allowed. For example, can you put a 'delivered' envelope into 'sent' status?

Lastly, is there a better way to get this kind of technical help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find all the possible envelope status at [Envelope Status](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Status%20and%20Managing%20Group/EnvelopeStatus.htm#Envelope). Currently there is no official documentation with status transition, the status description is pretty explanatory and it should help you in understanding the status flow. There are few statuses which are called terminal status and envelope once reached terminal status cannot be altered. Terminal statuses are `Completed, Voided, Declined`.